# How to set a ProtoBuf field which is an empty message in Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

The following are the contents of the Google Protocol Buffer (.proto) file

```
message First
{
    required uint32 field1 = 1;

    optional MessageType1 request = 2;
}

message MessageType1
{
}
```

I want to set the MessageType1 field request. But I get this as an error:

```
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field "request" in protocol message object.
```

How to set the value of this empty message in Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got this in the source code of Message class in Proto Buffer.

```
  def SetInParent(self):
    """Mark this as present in the parent.

    This normally happens automatically when you assign a field of a
    sub-message, but sometimes you want to make the sub-message
    present while keeping it empty.  If you find yourself using this,
    you may want to reconsider your design."""
```

So the way to set such an empty message is to call this function:

```
first.request.SetInParent()
```

Comment: I would have NEVER figured that out! Your answer is a blessing! Wish I searched for it yesterday! Would have saved me 8 hours of frustration!